# Post request, req.body undefined

Tags: express, post

**My Code**

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())


app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("Hello World!")
})

app.post('/', (req, res)=>{

    console.log(req.Body);

    res.send(`Name is`)
})

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server runing on port 5000");
})
```

**when i send post request it shows error**

SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 6
at JSON.parse ()
at parse (E:\Saylani IT Lab\JavaScript\Express-JS\Assignement 1\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
at E:\Saylani IT Lab\JavaScript\Express-JS\Assignement 1\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (E:\Saylani IT Lab\JavaScript\Express-JS\Assignement 1\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (E:\Saylani IT Lab\JavaScript\Express-JS\Assignement 1\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\Saylani IT Lab\JavaScript\Express-JS\Assignement 1\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8oFA.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a JSON syntax problem in your request:

Try `{"name":"Zaman"}` instead of `{name:"Zaman"}`